# Why new VS2013 project's functions are unresolved in linking if file is .cpp, but ok if file is .c

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

I'm linking all the native libs to a .dll which is used in WPF application.

I'm done this with other projects that are compiled to libs but the latest one does not work somehow, although all seems to be same way. I did like this:

.h:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H_
#define MYHEADER_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {   
#endif

void  MySetLoginResultCallback(int(*Callback)(int Ok, const char *UserName));


#ifdef __cplusplus
} // end of extern "C"
#endif
#endif // MYHEADER_H_
```

.cpp:

```
typedef int(*LoginResultCB_t)(int IsOk, const char *UserName);
LoginResultCB_t             gLoginResultCB;

void MySetLoginResultCallback(LoginResultCB_t pCB)
{
    gLoginResultCB = pCB;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MyLoginResultCB(int Ok, cons char *UserName)
{
   if (gLoginResultCB)
       return gLoginResultCB(Ok, UserName);

   return -1;
}
```

MyLoginResultCB is imported to WPF exe and called from there. In initialization the MySetLoginResultCallback is called from a C-file in native .dll.

In .dll linking I get unresolved error from MySetLoginResultCallback (which is called in native .c file). If I leave the header exactly the same and rename .cpp -> .c and remove extern "C" the .dll linking succeeds. What am I missing here?

call from aini.c

```
MySetLoginResultCallback(XpAfterLoginCB);
```

error:

1>aini.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MySetLoginResultCallback referenced in function _InitNoAKit

Comment: Can you please show how you use these functions? And also include the *exact* error (complete and unedited, and preferably the whole build log)?

Comment: Did you forget to include the header in the ".cpp"?

Comment: what u mean: include the header in .cpp? Why would i need to do that? I am calling from a .c file and there header is included

Comment: @matti `extern "C"` must be applied to the definition or the function will not get C linkage. It doesn't magically become a function with C linkage just because some header somewhere declares such a function.

Comment: I have to disagree because i have like 30 functions that prove this. The extern "C" for those is defined only in header and there's no problem calling those from C-file

Comment: @molbdnilo: Now I understood! The answer is to include the header which has declarations to .cpp file with definitions! Thank you!

Comment: @matti I forgot one detail that's a bit confusing: if the compiler has already "seen" the `extern "C"` declaration when it compiles the definition, it's applied automatically. That's why it works when you include the header in the source file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your .cpp file, you're defining a function `MySetLoginResultCallback` with C++ language linkage. That's a *different* function than the function `MySetLoginResultCallback` with C language linkage declared in the .h file.

The correct solution would be to add C language linkage to the .cpp file:

```
extern "C" {

typedef int(*LoginResultCB_t)(int IsOk, const char *UserName);
LoginResultCB_t             gLoginResultCB;

void MySetLoginResultCallback(LoginResultCB_t pCB)
{
    gLoginResultCB = pCB;
}

}
```

Notice that function types have language linkage too, which means that the typedef `LoginResultCB_t` has to be declared with C language linkage in the .cpp file also, because the parameter is declared as such in the .h file.

Comment: Thanks. I have done exactly the way I described elsewhere. So that extern "C" is defined ONLY  in header for functions called in native .dll. There it works. I try ur suggestion, but I don't understand why "my way" works in other projects / libs.

Comment: yup, ur way works. thanks again. now I wonder should I make another question why my way works with another lib if it shouldn't....

Answer (score 0):

The reason the way that extern "C" definitions ONLY in .h file worked in other projects/libs is that I included my header file with function declarations in my .cpp file with the definitions. Thanks to @molbdnilo to point this out!